# Codeigniter: Call to undefined function (model)

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, model, undefined

I get the following error:

> - Fatal error: Call to undefined function getAll() in
>     ...application\controllers\restserver.php on line 18
> - A PHP Error was encountered
> - Severity: Error
> - Message: Call to undefined function get()
> - Filename: controllers/restserver.php
> - Line Number: 24
> - Backtrace:

And I have the following Controller: **restserver.php**

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class Restserver extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function appproviders_get() {
        $this->load->model('appproviders_model');
        $this->response($this->appproviders_model>getAll());
   }

    public function appprovider_get() {
        $data = array('returned: '. $this->get('id'));
        $this->load->model('appproviders_model');
        $this->response($this->appproviders_model>get($data));
   }
}
```

And the following model: **appproviders_model.php**

```
class appproviders_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct(){

    parent::__construct();//Call the model constructor
}

function get($id = 0)
{
    $this -> db -> select('appprovider.*');
    $this -> db -> from('appprovider');
    $this -> db -> join('appusers','appprovider.userID = appusers.id','left');
    $this -> db -> where('appprovider.id', $id);

    $query = $this -> db -> get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

function getAll()
{
    $this -> db -> select('appprovider.*, appusers.name as name');
    $this -> db -> from('appprovider');
    $this -> db -> join('appusers','appprovider.userID = appusers.id','left');
    $this -> db -> where('appprovider.status', 1);

    $query = $this -> db -> get();

    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        $row = $query->row();
        return $row;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
    }
}
```

And I'm using the following RESTful server implementation for CodeIgniter:

https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

Any idea why when I call from the browser:

```
.../restserver/appprovider?id=1;format=json
```

or

```
.../restserver/appproviders?format=json
```

I get the errors detailed at the beginning of the post? 
It is indeed detecting the model but not its functions.

Must be something so simple, but I cannot find the error and I'm going totally crazy ...

Comment: You're missing a dash in your syntax: `appproviders_model>get($data)` should be `appproviders_model->get($data)`, and the same for the getAll line.

Comment: Yeap, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

You should replace

`$this->response($this->appproviders_model>getAll());`

to

`$this->response($this->appproviders_model->getAll());`